# How can I set up a BCC option for automated messages?

Tags: civievent

Our administrator wants to receive a copy of the expiration email Civi sends when an event registration has automatically expires (Message templates -> System workflow messages -> Events - Pending Registration Expiration Notice).

I am trying to figure out how to do this as a Civi user - not as a developer! I came across this discussion but can't quite understand what the status of this feature is at the moment:

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=17872.0

Could someone help? (We are running CiviCRM 4.5.3 on Joomla! 3.3.3)

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a second scheduled reminder for the membership and have it go to the administrator only.  You could even customize the message to be more concise and provide information that he or she needs (like the contact's full name and a link to the contact record on the backend) but wouldn't naturally go in the email to the member.

Although this wouldn't be the precise email that the member receives, it'll be driven by the same process, and you can set the same timing for it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the thread doesn't indicate this is possible for a non-developer, and it would require some coding. We could do some custom code for you - email me at joe dot murray at jmaconsulting dot biz if you are interested.